# C++/Win32 Best way for me to start a thread on Windows 2000+

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I'm looking for the lightest (in terms of .exe size increase) way to start a thread on Win 2000 or later. Thread is to be run in the main processes address space.

Hopefully I can do this with one include: #include windows.h alone.

Comment: Personally I'd only support XP and above - Win2k is very, very old.

Comment: It's sort of irrelevant how old it is if your customers are still using it, though. With that logic, XP is also "very, very old". Windows 8 will be out soon, time to drop support for anything but Win 7 and 8. If only...

Comment: Also, the W2K and XP API are almost identical, not much difference across things like this.

Comment: If you're developing stuff for Win2K you might find the Windows 2003 DDK helpful (though maybe a little difficult to work with).

Comment: Also don't forget to `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`, it strips out some extraneous stuff

Comment: @Mehrdad Uh, why? Just define `_WIN32_WINNT` as `0x0500` before you include `Windows.h`. What's the motivation behind using the Win 2003 DDK?

Comment: @CodyGray: At least for Windows XP and later, it tends to provide tinier executables (with respect to the CRT), since it links with `msvcrt.dll` instead of statically linking with a gigantic CRT or dynamically linking with `msvcr90.dll` or whatever. And since `msvcrt.dll` is shared everywhere, it pretty much doesn't use up any more physical memory for the CRT that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CreateThread API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx

There is a nice example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: OK, how do I forcefully close the thread from the main application (CloseHandle() does not terminate the thread)?

Comment: There are thousands of posts about terminating/stopping threads on SO.  My preferred approach is to not explicitly do so at all, ie. use lifetime-of-app threads and/or thread pools.  The basic problem is that only the OS is any good at terminating threads and, even then, it's only always safe to do so upon process termination, (ie. app close).

Comment: @Martin James - I agree completely, but there are times that you still need to forcefully terminate a thread for one reason or another, but only as an absolute last resort.

Comment: **Be very careful with `TerminateThread`!** It is not designed for general usage. The name *terminate* is a good clue. As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717.aspx) says: *"TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases. You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time of the termination."*. There are more details in the linked documentation.

Comment: Personally, I don't think the warnings in the docs are quite strong enough. Some of the commenters agree with me. Martin James is correct. There's rarely a good reason to forcibly terminate a thread yourself. If you want to end a thread, use `CloseHandle` and let the system take care of it. (Note that you must call `CloseHandle` anyway; creating a thread sets its reference count to +2. Calling `CloseHandle` decrements it by 1. The system decrements it by 1. That puts it at 0 so that it can be destroyed. Forgetting to call `CloseHandle` is a memory leak, at least until your app is closed.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Win32 API has a [`CreateThread` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx), the only thing you need to include is `Windows.h`. This creates a new thread for a process. It definitely works in Windows 2000, and even further back.

A sample is available here on MSDN: [Creating Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516.aspx). A Google search also reveals [this article on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13557/Creating-Threads-using-the-CreateThread-API). You'll probably find a lot more.

Comment: OK, how do I forcefully close the thread from the main application (CloseHandle() does not terminate the thread)?